# Minus sign removed using number formatting with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, format

I am using the number format plugin for jQuery, specifically [jQuery Number Format: Redux](https://www.customd.com/articles/14/jquery-number-format-redux), and for some reason negative numbers are reformatted as positive.

If I have

```
<span format='float'>-50</span>
```

and call

```
$('span[format="float"]').number(true, 2);
```

The negative is removed and returns 50.00 instead of -50.00

see [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/uj5hn69x/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the docs, `.number(true, ...)` is described as such

> the 'true' signals we should read and replace the text

It looks like the first parameter of `number()` can also be a number itself. So when evaluating the number of `<span format='float'>-50</span>`, let's just try to pass the elements own text explicitly in as such

```
$('span[format="float"]').number($('span[format="float"]').text(), 2); // -50
```

And it's works? Odd. Perhaps a bug?

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/nuuw2u76/)

I see you [submitted a issue](https://github.com/customd/jquery-number/issues/83) on this. We'll likely get confirmation this is not intentional behavior.

Per discussion, a possible workaround for formatting multiple elements may include...

```
<span format='float'>-50</span>
<span format='float'>-20</span>
<span format='float'>-10</span>
```

---

```
$("[format='float']").each(function() {
    $(this).number($(this).text(), 2)
})
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0ta2tz37/) - multiple tags

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, if you have multiple spans this workaround fails... https://jsfiddle.net/1z5ew3tm/1/

Comment: @Ben this is a simplistic example. You're likely referencing the same jQuery selector for multiples. [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t1rhboy/) shows multiple elements, each referencing _themselves_

Comment: I see. Hopefully a fix will be released soon. I have many elements that need to be formatted, and would hate to have to reference each one explicitly. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Ben I updated answer to include a possible workaround for you give it a look